# django drag and drop feature with dropzone

Tags: jquery, django, dropzone.js

I want to implement drag and drop feature in my form where I want to submit files. My template looks like :

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/dropzone.css" %}">
<form id='my-awesome-dropzone' class="dropzone" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.files }}

</form>
<button id="submit-all">
        Submit all files
    </button>
{% endblock %}

<script src="{% static "js/dropzone.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       Dropzone.options.myDropzone = { 

autoProcessQueue: false,
paramName: "files",
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 100,
maxFilesize: 5,
maxFiles: 10,
init : function() {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
                myDropzone = this;

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                    // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                });

                // You might want to show the submit button only when
                // files are dropped here:
                this.on("addedfile", function() {
                    // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
                });

            }
        };
    </script>
```

I am getting the css genuinely but I am still getting browse button instead of drag and drop space.. Css is taking its space but browse button is not removed ?

Am I doing something wrong ? 
Need help ?